# python textwrap -- break up path name on / character

Tags: python

I would like to use the `textwrap` package to break up a long directory path e.g.,:

```
'/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/analysis/one_long_dir_name/another_long_dir_name/an_even_longer_dir_name'
```

but I would like the break to take place only on `/` characters so as to not break up an actual directory name.

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) or the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) modules, both part of Python’s stdlib. They contain functions to split a path string into its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `textwrap` package but you can create your own simple function to do the same. Like this

```
def wrap(text, limit):
    count = 0
    fin = []
    for temp in text.split('/'):
        count += len(temp)
        if count >limit:
            break
        else:
            fin.append(temp)
    return '/'.join(fin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 2 solutions here.

a) Short and Simple - without using `textwrap`

```
sample_text =  '/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/analysis/one_long_dir_nam/another_long_dir_name/an_even_longer_dir_name'
sample_text = sample_text.replace('/', '\n')
print(sample_text)
```

b) Using `textwrap`

```
import textwrap
sample_text =  '/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/analysis/one_long_dir_name/another_long_dir_name/an_even_longer_dir_name'
lines = sample_text.split("/")
lists = (textwrap.TextWrapper(width=100,break_long_words=False).wrap(word) for word in lines)
result  = "\n".join("\n".join(words) for words in lists)
print(result)
```